Problems with the setspace package in LuaLaTeX after updating TeXLive on Windows 10
Problems with the setspace package after updating TeXLive on Windows 10.
MWE:
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = utf-8
%==========================================================
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}
%========================================
\babelfont{rm}[Scale=0.976]{TimesNewRoman}
%========================================
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\spacing{0.976}
%\spacing{1.464}
\begin{document}
Hello World!

Hello World!

Hello World!
\end{document}

Gives an error:
! LaTeX Error: Loading a class or package in a group.

If you disable \usepackage{graphicx}, then everything works.
Help me fix it.

I suggest you replace \spacing{1.464} with \setstretch{1.464}. (By the way, how did you land on 1.464 as the stretch factor?)

I took the value 1.464 from an article in Russian. To make it look like MS Word.
Will the setstretch command only change the spacing of the body text? What will change after your adjustment?
@Mico

Indeed, \setstretch affects the line spacing in the body of the document.

\spacing should never be used as a command it is the internal definition of the \begin{spacing} environment which should be used within a document.
So this input was always in error and would have produced a low level warning about end occuring within a group at the end of the document. More recent LaTeX releases detect this error earlier if you load a package within a group rather than at the top level.
As noted in comments the command form is \setstretch
